# jQuery plugin authoring - extending the jQuery object and also the jQuery.fn object

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm not an expert on this, this is my first foray into creating a jQuery plugin.

What I want to do is create a jQuery plugin that can be called both on a dom object, but also independently.

For example, if my plugin is to `alert()` something I would like it to be able to be called both ways below:

```
$.tcAlert('Hello World');
// Resulting code:
//
// alert('Hello World');
//

$('#myDiv').tcAlert();
// Resulting code:
//
// theText = $('myDiv').text();
// alert(theText);
//
```

Obviously this is a very simple example, but I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to go about creating a plugin like this. Will I, in effect, have to create the jQuery extension and then the jQuery.fn extension references the original extension?

Any help/pointers would be very helpful thank you.

Comment: You should keep in mind that the calling context will be different depending on the location from which your plugin is invoked. Depending on what your plugin does, you may need to test to see how it was called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if it’s a function that does something with an element, you should write it in plugin format, e.g. `$.fn.myPlugin = function() {};`. If it’s just an utility function, add it to the global `jQuery` / `$` object, e.g. `$.myFunction = function() {};`

Your example could be written as follows:

```
$.tcAlert = function(string) {
  alert(string);
};

$.fn.tcAlert = function() {
  // call the `tcAlert` function, passing the .text() of the current element as the argument
  $.tcAlert(this.text());
  // allow chaining
  return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not always know whether a selector has matched any elements or not.

To handle this, do the following..

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function() {

  //First check length of matched elements

  if(this.length < 1){
    //standalone functionality
  }
  else{
    return this.each(function(){
        //do things to matched elements
        //where, $(this) refers to current element
    });
  }

}
```